# Force.com IDE: Syntax Highlighting Disappears after Saving a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, ide, syntax-highlighting

While using the standalone version of the Force.com IDE (API version 28), syntax highlighting always disappears whenever I save a Visualforce page.

If I close the file and reopen it, the syntax highlighting comes back.  If I CTRL-A, CTRL-X, CTRL-V to select all, cut, then paste back the page contents, the syntax highlighting comes back. Unfortunately, the minute I save the page to the server, I'm back to all black text on a white background.

Has anyone else has experienced this?  Better yet, does anyone know of a fix or workaround that I can implement to make this annoying behavior stop?

Comment: I have experienced this, but I haven't looked for a solution yet

Comment: I've been looking for an answer, too, with no luck. I'm hoping that if anyone does figure this out, they will land on this question and share the answer. :-)